# FileNotFoundException when CREATING a google drive file

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I have an app on the google with firebase set up and users can log in to the app and I want to be able to store app data.

The GoogleSignInOptions is set as follows

```
GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(Scope(Scopes.DRIVE_APPFOLDER))
            .build()
```

And the createFile method is

```
public Task<String> createFile() {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, () -> {
            File fileMetadata = new File();
            fileMetadata.setName("profile.json");
            fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList("appDataFolder"));

            java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("profile.json");

            FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("application/json", filePath);

            File file = mDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                    .setFields("id")
                    .execute();

            return file.getId();
        });
    }
```

but fore some reason, calling the createFile method throws the following exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: profile.json (No such file or directory)
```

why ? for some more context, this is tested in the debug version of the app

Comment: Are you creating a file or reading a file?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a file whose content is the content of a local file. However, the path to the local file is in the "current working directory" - which is usually the directory from which the JVM was invoked. Have you checked that this file exists locally in that path? Why aren't you giving a proper, full path for the local `profile.json`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, you were right with the fact that it didn't found the path of the local file. calling the 'path' method of my local file just returned "profile.json" though. I tried to just delete the 'mediaContent' part of the 'create' method, now it doesn't crash but when I try to list my drive files, the filelist is empty

Comment: Your local file doesn't represent your real file. You have to find the path in the operating system and create the `java.io.File` object with the *real* path, not just `profile.json`. This isn't connected to Google Drive. If there is a second problem, you should list it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problematic line was

```
 java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("profile.json");
```

I needed to put the real path of the file and not just "profile.json"

Comment: What is the "real path" then?